# I am trying to make it so on key pressed a part inserts in the game in front of you in Roblox Studio but I don't know how

Tags: lua, roblox

Im trying to make a game on roblox but this is the only thing thats bugging me.
Please help.

Comment: Heyo, welcome to StackOverflow! Before you ask a question it is usually expected that you have tried to solve a problem and need help understanding why your solution doesn't work. If you need a place to get started, I would recommend : https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-input for pressing buttons, and https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Create-Parts-via-Code for placing thing with code. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: If you have tried to solve the problem, as Kylaa has described, and you're having issue, please add a snippet of your code to question and more detail of what is not working as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for here is to create a Remote Event the fires from the client to tell the server to create the new part. There is a good example on the Roblox Developer site title "Remote Functions and Events".

In essence it is:

CLIENT SIDE

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local createPartEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("CreatePartEvent")

createPartEvent:FireServer()
```

SERVER SIDE

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local createPartEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent", ReplicatedStorage)
createPartEvent.Name = "CreatePartEvent"

local function onCreatePartFired(player)
    print(player.Name, "wants to create a part")
    local newPart = Instance.new("Part")
    newPart.Position = Vector3.new(0, 20, 0)
    newPart.Parent = game.Workspace
end

createPartEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(onCreatePartFired)
```

As part of the Client Side event, you are going to have to send the co-ords of the player (+ a few studs) where to create the part, and then on the server side let "newPart.Position" = those co-ords.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.

Comment: But still I don't get how you get how you use a key on press like I dont know how you add it in the code but thanks for a part of it.